# Attached Properties as XAML Elements

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I've got a class of attached properties:

```
public static class XamlProps
{
    #region Attached Properties

    private static readonly DependencyProperty FooProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Foo",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(XamlProps),
        null);

    public static void SetFoo(DependencyObject obj, string action)
    {
        obj.SetValue(FooProperty, action);
    }
}
```

And I use these properties in my XAML:

```
<Border me:XamlProps.Foo="Foo to the Bar">
```

But now I want a larger value in this property, so I'd like to use it as an element:

```
<Border>
    <me:XamlProps.Foo>Foo to the Bar</me:XamlProps.Foo>
</Border>
```

But now Silverlight doesn't call SetFoo() anymore.  How do I get this to work?

On Windows Phone 7 if it matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to specify the type if you use that syntax:

```
<Border>
    <me:XamlProps.Foo>
        <sys:String>Foo to the Bar</sys:String>
    </me:XamlProps.Foo>
</Border>
```

Where the sys namespace maps to System.  You also need to define GetFoo ...

Probably a copy-paste typo, but in the registration

```
typeof(XamlActions)
```

should be

```
typeof(XamlProps)
```

Comment: Is there a way to wrap this in a <![CDATA[ ]]> ?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048223/silverlight-xaml-textblock-text-with-cdata-not-showing-up-at-runtime

Answer (score 1):

You should never rely on the SetFoo being called. Anything can simply call SetValue(FooProperty, "blah") and bypass it.

You should define a [PropertyChangedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557330%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) in your DependencyProperty.[Register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597502%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) call to be notified of changes.

Comment: I don't depend on SetFoo() being called except in this case for stepping through to see if it's set.  And ultimately I don't actually want changes to these.  This is an initial-behavior thing, not ongoing.

Comment: Ok, but unless you are explicitly calling SetFoo, there are no guarantees that it will be called via XAML.